# Receive a broadcast AFTER user click on OK button AFTER uninstall was completed

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, action, uninstallation

I placed all the receiver tags in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<receiver android:name="my.package.MyBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And implemented my `BroadcastReceiver` subclass:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive( final Context context, final Intent intent ) {
        Log.w( "RECEIVED!!!!!!!" );
    }
}
```

This works very fine!!! But... The `onReceive` method is called **AFTER** uninstall was completed but **BEFORE** users press **OK** at confirmation activity showed by native system.

I wanna, if exists, receive a broadcast **AFTER** user press **OK**.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible. Why would you need to do it after the OK is pressed?

Comment: It's possible because ZDbox do it in uninstall batch mode! App link at Google Play: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zdworks.android.toolbox

Comment: This is an app that uses root privileges. Unless yours also is going to use root privileges, I suggest you assume that they can do things your app or another normal app could not. If you are really dying to know, you could try emailing the developer.

Answer (score 0):

I made a workaround and works so far.

The activity was calling uninstall intent was flagged like that:

```
<activity
    android:name="my.package.MyActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:noHistory="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
```

The flag `android:noHistory="true"` removes my `Activity` from history after be stopped by another new `Activity` so after user click on "OK" button in confirmation view after uninstall completed, the user goes back to home screen view.

I removed this flag so I placed my code to be executed after uninstall completed and confirmed by user on `onRestart` method in `MyActivity`.

*It's a workaround, if has a way to get user confirmation after complete uninstall I don't know!*